# Delete certain rows of a matrix in julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I am learning julia in a university course and I have to do an assigment but I don't know how to preprocess the data. Hi have a matrix with patterns distributed in rows. Its dimension is 1521x4.

The first attribute take values from 0 to 4 and I want to delete patterns (rows) whose first attribute has a value of less than 4. How could I do it using Julia?

I know that there are a lot of operations to work with matrices and arrays in julia but I don't find a suitable one for my problem.

I have this code:

```
using DelimitedFiles

files_and_dirs = readdir()
for f in files_and_dirs
    if filesize(f) == 0
        rm(f)
    end
end

filter(endswith(".lxyr"), files_and_dirs)

#Inicializamos la matriz con 1 fila y el numero de atributos de columnas
global dataset = zeros(1,4)

#134 = Numero maximo que queremos leer
for count in 1:134
    name = "img"*string(count)*".lxyr"
    if isfile(name) #Checkeamos si existe
        matrix = readdlm(name)
        global dataset = vcat(dataset, matrix) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code does this (all code from your question written in one line):

```
dataset = [readdlm(name) for name in string.("img",1:134,".lxyr") if isfile(name) && filesize(name) > 0]
```

It is not clear what you need - filter matrices of rows from a matrix

If you want to filter dataset for matrices that have in first row values of at least 4:

```
filter!(m -> all(m[1,:] .>= 4), matrices)
```

If you have a matrix such as:

```
m = collect(reshape(1:16,4,4))
```

Than you can select rows having values above some threshold with a code such as:

```
@view m[[all(row .>= 2) for row in eachrow(m)],:]
```